# rasterize RasterBrick object

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to `rasterize` a `SpatialPolygon` object by a `RasterBrick` object. The documentation of the `raster::rasterize` function explicitly says this is allowed. Here's what I am doing

```
# load the raster package
library("raster")

# create a raster brick object using the example from the brick function documentation
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

# create a SpatialPolygon object using the example from the function documentation
Sr1 = Polygon(10*cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),10*c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(10*cbind(c(5,4,2,5),10*c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(10*cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Sr4 = Polygon(10*cbind(c(5,6,6,5,5),c(4,4,3,3,4)), hole = TRUE)

Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "s1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "s2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3, Sr4), "s3/4")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)

# crop
clip1 = crop(b, extent(SpP))

# rasterize returns an error, but documentation says it should return a RasterBrick object
clip2 = rasterize(SpP, b, mask = T)
Error in v[, r] <- rrv : 
     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

# however, if I used only one layer, all would be fine
clip2 = rasterize(SpP, b[[1]], mask = T)
```

Of course, I could loop over the brick's layers, but as I understand it, that would defeat the purpose of a brick object.

I want to use `clip2` to then get the histogram of pixel values in the layers.

```
vals = getValues(clip2)
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error, and how to go around it efficiently?

Comment: It looks to me like that is a bug. The error occurs inside `raster:::.polygonsToRaster`, which you can view here: https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/4d218a7565d3994682557b8ae4d5b52bc2f54241/R/rasterizePolygons.R#L395  ...Unfortunately, the github repo is a read-only mirror so you can't file an issue there. You could try contacting the package author via email.

Comment: @clbieganek, thanks. this is indeed a bug, and should be fixed soon. Am answering it below, so others can know what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @clbieganek's comment above, this is indeed a bug in the current CRAN version 2.6-7. Author Michael Sumner says this should be fixed in the next release, see https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg249242.html.